# Handle LinkButton click event via AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

We have a custom control grid in our project. I have decided to modify the grid so it can be switched from regular `PostBack` functionality to AJAX only functionality. I created a WS which can be called from Javascript, which renders the control and returns the output HTML to the client where it is inserted in to the DOM via JS.

All of this works nicely. My issue now is that the grid sort headers and paging links are `LinkButton`s and are made to do full page `PostBack`s. Since I would like to make the grid switchable from "regular" to AJAX mode via a property, I thought about handling the AJAX functionality by modifying the client side behavior of asp.net for these `LinkButton` controls. The problem is that I have no idea where to start on this.

Can anyone recommend a resource to get me along my way? I can't seem to find any information in my Google searches. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try prevent default binded event and use ajax

```
$('th a','#gridview').click(function(e){

  e.preventDefault();
  var headerText=$(this).text();

  $.post('service-url',{sort:headerText, page:1}, function(result)
  {
    $('#gridview-container').html(result);
  }

});
```